# How to prevent generation of substitions

Tags: sympy

Sympy sometimes automatically generates substitutions in my experessions:

How can I prevent this? Or, how can I remove the substitution from the expression?

```
from sympy import *
R, T = symbols('R T', cls=Function)
u = symbols('u', cls=Function)
x, y, z= symbols('x y z')

R(u(x,y)).diff(x)
```

gives

```
Derivative(u(x, y), x)*Subs(Derivative(R(_xi_1), _xi_1), (_xi_1,), (u(x, y),))
```

I'd like to have

```
Derivative(u(x, y), x)*Derivative(R(u(x, y), (u(x, y)))
```

PS: http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#subs says "When evaluating derivatives at a point that is not a symbol, a Subs object is returned."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will give you what you ask for

```
>>> s=R(u(x,y)).diff(x)
>>> s.replace(Subs, lambda a,b,c: a.xreplace(dict(zip(b,c))))
```

(It will revert to a Subs instance if you apply the doit method.)

Comment: This should probably be changed. Subs should only be used when it is impossible to represent as a Derivative (like at a numerical point).

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for. Now, some other problem arises, but that is a different story...